# How can I tell Guzzle to safely ignore ssl.certificate_authority in Behat testing? (Development server)

Tags: 8, testing

On a sandbox install of Drupal running behat under the [Behat Drupal Extension](https://github.com/jhedstrom/drupalextension), I'm trying to fun the following feature:

```
@api
  Scenario: Logged in User
    Given I am logged in as a user with the "administrator" role
    And I am on '/user'
    Then I should see the heading "User"
```

**Inital cURL error**

I get this error complaining about the SSL certificate.

```
cURL error 60: Issuer certificate is invalid. (GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException)
```

**My first attempt to ignore fails**

This makes sense. This is a sandbox on RHEL 7 where I just activated mod_ssl. In order to try to ignore this, I added the `ssl.certificate_authority: false` to behat.yml. Since that I now see this...

> No method can handle the ssl.certificate_authority config key
>   (InvalidArgumentException)

**behat.yml set up**

```
 default:
      suites:
        default:
          contexts:
            - FeatureContext
            - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
            - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
      extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
          goutte: ~
          sessions:
            my_session:
              goutte:
                guzzle_parameters:
                  ssl.certificate_authority: false
          selenium2: ~
          base_url: http://localhost
        Drupal\DrupalExtension:
          blackbox: ~
          api_driver: 'drupal'
          drush:
            alias: 'local'
          drupal:
            drupal_root: '/var/www/html'
```

**Update**
Based on information from the [Github issue queue](https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/issues/47), I have changed my

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading on https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/doc/index.rst#drivers, I tried the following in the behat.yml file.

```
default:
  suites:
    default:
      contexts:
        - FeatureContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\DrupalContext
        - Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      goutte:
        guzzle_parameters:
          verify: false
      selenium2: ~
      base_url: http://localhost
    Drupal\DrupalExtension:
      blackbox: ~
      api_driver: 'drupal'
      drush:
        alias: 'local'
      drupal:
        drupal_root: '/var/www/html'
```

It worked.

I needed to find out *how* to tell Guzzle/cURL to not worry about validating any CERT. Again, I would not do this under a production server, but for the sake of a local development environment, I'd give it a go.

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: for me either  :(